# Web app for synchronizing data between two systems

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services, synchronization, polling

What I want to do is this: create an ASP.NET MVC web app that periodically looks for new or updated data from an external API (eg, a new order created or modified in an inventory management system), and then sends this data to another system. Similar sort of thing to [this](http://zapier.com) - I have tried using it, but I've found it's a bit too limited for some of the things I wanted to do.

I am currently trying to figure out the best way to go about this. I imagine that it will work like this:

1. Periodically (using a timer?) pull the data from one system's API, and cache the id and DateUpdated fields (in a local database I assume) for each item.
2. If there are any changes against the cached data, then convert the item to appropriate format if needed and post to the second API.

I would be connecting to a few different third party systems, which for the most part do not support web hooks etc, so I assume polling and caching is the only option.

Am I on the right track? Haven't been able to find a lot of resources on this sort of thing, so would appreciate any advice.

Comment: doesn't sound like this should be a web app, you have something that needs to be running constantly and doesn't involve a user interface

Comment: @Robert Levy
I am planning on including a basic UI for reporting/logging, as well as allowing the user to add additional accounts for the connected systems.

Comment: This sounds like a better implementation would be a windows service since it will run constantly.  If you need to run it as a webapp, this is a good alternative: http://hangfire.io/

Comment: You can also go for windows task scheduler which you can run at specific time intervals. You can point a console application where all your business logic runs.